# java servlets init and destroy

Tags: java, servlets

servlets uses init() to initialize servlets status and destroy to clean up. Is there a special class name we need to put init() and destroy()? How does servlets know where to find these methods?

asp.net has a global.asax to handle similar thing in asp.net , servlets has a special class to do the same thing?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be in the same class as your Servlet class.

All servlets inherit this method from the base Servlet class. Unless you want to do some additional processing, the inherited method should be fine and you dont need to override this method in each of your servlets.

Comment: but what i have a bunch of servlets class? Which class i should put these two methods in?

Comment: All servlets inherit this method from the base Servlet class. Unless you want to do some additional processing, the inherited method should be fine and you dont need to override this method in each of your servlets.

Comment: @icn, you would implement `init()` in whichever Servlet class(es) you want to have special initialization logic in

Comment: so even I override these two methods in one of my very often requests servlets class, web server/JVM will ensure these two methods being run only once?

Comment: @icn yes. The lifecycle is handled by the servlet container (catalina etc). You don't need to do anything manual.

Comment: yes, init/destroy are not a part of the regular http request cycle.

Answer (score 3):

Servlets will ultimately be a subclass of the `javax.servlet.Servlet` class, which defines those methods.

Comment: so i can put these two methods in any of my servlets class and just put once, the JVM or tomcat server will look up where these two methods in ?

Comment: Right, the Servlet container will access your class as Servlet object, and invoke those methods for you.

Answer (score 1):

Servlets are deployed in the Container(Web Server/Application Server),That container will take care of initializing or destroying of servlets,and we dont have predefined classes to initialise and destroy for servlets,if we use particular class that means we are depending on that class(Tightly Coupling) thats not recomended.
Now we are using GenericServlet,and HttpServlet classes for that methods..once refer J2EE API and find this classes and methods in them..

Answer (score 0):

The JVM which runs the Servlet, looks for those methods only in classes, which extend `Servlet` or `HttpServlet`.

Answer (score 0):

Servlets are managed objects. This means that they are executed inside a container that manages their lifecycles (instantiates the servlets, call their relevant methods when it is appropiate, and releases them). The container (Tomcat, Glassfish, ...) knows when to call these methods at the right time because it is implemented that way, there is nothing special about that.

If the container had a bug, it could even call, say, destroy() at init time and init() at destroy time. That bug would be fixed quickly, though.